# MVC3 Generic CRUD Controllers, Services and Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, controller, crud

We are attempting to create a generic CRUD controller in our MVC3 application which can handle the following actions Edit (Create/Edit), Delete and List (I have already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358081/mvc-basecontroller-handling-crud-operations)).  The project has the Web (MVC) layer, Service (BLL) layer and a Repository (DB) layer.  We are using constructor dependency injection as follows:

```
SERVICE LAYER
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public MySerivce(IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        this._myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IMyObject> GetObjects(int intParentKey)
    {
        return (IMyObject)_myRepository.GetObjects(intParentKey).Select(o => new MyObject(o));;
    }
}


CONTROLLER
public class MyController
{
    private IMyService _myService;

    public MyController(IMyService myService)
    {
        this._myService = myService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", new List<MyFormModel>(_myService.GetObjects(intKeyValue).Select(a => new MyFormModel(a))));
    }
}
```

The goal is to have a generic CRUD controller, but the difficulty is that the controllers will need to have knowledge of the MyFormModel object as well as a specific service.  We would also like to have a generic service which handles the GetObjects, SaveObject, DeleteObject functions, but then that would need knowledge of the IMyObject interface, the MyObject implementation of IMyObject and the IMyRepository type.  It appears right now that doing all of this with dependency injection is somewhat complicated.

FYI, the Service layer needs to change on the fly within the WEB portion of the tool depending on the current configuration.

**In response to the generic CRUD comment, here is a BASE controller which accepts a BASE service through dependency injection:**

```
public abstract class BaseCRUDController<T>
    where T : class
{
    private IBaseService _baseService;

    public BaseCRUDController(IBaseService baseService)
    {
        this._baseService = baseService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Type classType = typeof(T);
        ConstructorInfo ciClass = classType.GetConstructor(new Type[] {});
        return View("Index", new List<T>(_baseService.GetObjects(intKey).Select(o => (T)ciClass.Invoke(new object[] { o }))));
    }
}
```

Obviously this generic controller is fairly straightforward, but the difficulty comes from the service side where the IMyObject and MyObject objects reside.  The definition of the generic BaseService will require you to include the types of all of the objects in the base controller which is what we are trying to avoid.  The code below could be way off the mark which is why I am asking for help:

```
SERVICE CLASS
public class MySerivce : BaseService<IMyObject, MyObject, DBObject>
{
    public MySerivce(IMyRepository myRepository) :
        base(myRepository)
    {
    }
}

BASE SERVICE INTERFACE
public interface IBaseService<IMT, MT, DT>
    where IMT : class
    where MT : class
    where DT : class
{
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Save(IMT model);
    void Delete(int intKey);
    IMT Get(int? intKey);
    IEnumerable<IMT> GetObjects(int intParentKey);
}


BASE SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION
public class BaseService<IMT, MT, DT> : IBaseService<IMT, MT, DT>
where IMT : class
where MT : class
where DT : class
{
private IBaseRepository _baseRepository;

public BaseService(IBaseRepository baseRepository)
{
    this._baseRepository = baseRepository;
}

public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Save(IMT model)
{
    List<ValidationResult> lResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

    if (Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null), lResults))
    {
        Type tDT = typeof(DT);
        ConstructorInfo ciDTClass = tDT.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        DT dtObject = (DT)ciDTClass.Invoke(new object[] { });
        Mapper.CreateMap<IMT, DT>();
        Mapper.Map(model, dtObject);

        _baseRepository.Save<DT>(dtObject);
    }

    return lResults;
}

public void Delete(int intKey)
{
    _baseRepository.Delete<DT>(intKey);
}

public IMT Get(int? intKey)
{
    Type tMT = typeof(MT);
    ConstructorInfo ciMTClass = tMT.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    DT dtObject = _baseRepository.Get<DT>(intKey);

    if (dtObject == null)
    {
        Type tDT = typeof(DT);
        ConstructorInfo ciDTClass = tDT.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        dtObject = (DT)ciDTClass.Invoke(new object[] { });
    }

    return (IMT)ciMTClass.Invoke(new object[] { dtObject });
}

public IEnumerable<IMT> GetObjects(int intParentKey)
{
    Type tMT = typeof(MT);
    ConstructorInfo ciMTClass = tMT.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    IEnumerable<DT> dbObjects = _baseRepository.GetObjects<DT>(intParentKey);

    return (IEnumerable<IMT>)dbObjects.Select(o => (MT)ciMTClass.Invoke(new object[] { o })); ;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _generic CRUD controller_? You want to put in different implementations of _IMyService_ (which is a non-generic interface) that handle different types of objects (like _MyObject_, _MyObject2_ etc.) but you don't want to tell your controller what objects the different services handle?

Comment: I guess generic is the wrong term.  I want a BASE controller which will the handle the Edit/Delete/List actions.  I will post another set of code for a better explanation.